# View all data in limit offset pagination

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using limit offset pagination in an API which is being used in two scenarios.

1. Where the pagination is needed. So as to show limited data in each page.
2. The API is being used in another place where I have to show all the datas.

Is there any way in Django limit offset pagination to view all the datas?

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to you view and add `all` as query parameter to you URL to get all rows.

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
    if 'all' in request.query_params:
        return None

    return super().paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
```

Comment: I added a custom pagination method and inside it I checked 'all' 
Thanks for the idea.
But I was searching for something with the Django inbuilt pagination without doing any tweaks

Answer (score 0):

This answer is the based on [@davit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5840704/davit-tovmasyan) answer. I need to change the method signature (**for Django 2.2**).

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
    if 'all' in self.request.query_params:
        return None

    return super().paginate_queryset(queryset)
```